# Questions about the behavior of getting Cursor of datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a question about getting Cursor

Target function:
https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore#Iterator.Cursor

As far as can be read from the following code, offset is set when getting a Cursor
https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/datastore/query.go#L702-L705

When I checked the result when this function was executed with the stack trace of GCP console, Insights displays a warning

```
Issue: Use of offset in datastore queries.
Description: Your app made 1 remote procedure calls to datastore.query () and datastore.next () using offset.
Recommendation: Use cursor instead of offset.
```

Query Details

```
g.co/gae/datastore/offset 10
g.co/gae/datastore/skipped 10
```

offset affects performance and billing, I want to avoid this behavior
Is there a way to avoid using offset? Or is this the correct behavior?

Comment: Did you checked https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/datastore/snippets/snippet_test.go SnippetIterator_Cursor() ?

Answer (score 1):

From [Offsets versus cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/query-cursors#offsets_versus_cursors):

> Although Cloud Datastore supports integer offsets, you should avoid
>   using them. Instead, use cursors. Using an offset only avoids
>   returning the skipped entities to your application, but these entities
>   are still retrieved internally. The skipped entities do affect the
>   latency of the query, and your application is billed for the read
>   operations required to retrieve them. Using cursors instead of offsets
>   lets you avoid all these costs.

The `q.offset` you're referring to is an internal variable used for the `Cursor` implementation, it's not the explicit query offset that the above quote mentions.

So you should be fine using `Cursor`.